# Sublime Text 2 replace multiple selections in one file from multiple selections in another file

Tags: replace, sublimetext2, selection

I have one file with multiple selections of `"ID" : "some-random-UUID"`

I have made a multiple selection of these `"some-random-UUID"`

Now in my other file I have `"ID" : "xyz"` and I want to replace the contents of the multiple selection `"xyz"` with the contents from the multiple selection in the first file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought.

Just copy the multiple selection (`"ID" : "some-random-UUID"`) from the first file.

Then paste the multiple selection into the second file (after I've done a multiple selection of `"ID" : "xyz"`)